# Search for a specific <tag> and divide the value inside the <tag> by X

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I'm new to XSLT, can someone give me a hand with this?

When in the source xml exists the tag , the value of that field has to be divided by 100.

In other words:

`<value>44000</value>` has to be transformed to `<value>440</value>`

The original xml can have any structure, the XSLT needs to iterate through the nodes and find that tag.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide an example of input XML and the required output.

Comment: The tittle of my previous question was misleading, so I asked it again using a proper title, since the division is not the only thing I need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the identity transformation template

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="foo">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select=". div 100"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

where `foo` is the name of the element where you want to change the value.

Comment: Not sure I understand, I've created a xsl file with only this inside:

<xsl:template match="value">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select=". div 100"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

Is that enough to make it work?.

Comment: Never mind, I thought that the first part of the answer was a template just to show me the format or something, I had to put it just like it was described in the answer. Thanks!.